# Check which checkbox is selected

Tags: java, android, checkbox, findviewbyid

I got a program that has 50+ checkboxes on one page.
And I need to check which boxes are selected.

I know I can do somehting like this:

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

if (cb1.isChecked){
//get Checkbox name
}
if (cb2.isChecked){
//get Checkbox name
}
```

But if I have to do this with more then 50 checkboxes, that would take some time.
Is their a faster way to check which on is selected? Something like:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i<checkBox.length; i++){
  CheckBox cb+i = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkBox+i);

     if (cb+i.isChecked){
     //get Checkbox name
     }
}
```

Maybe also good to say: you can select more then 1 checkbox.
I hope you know what I mean.

Thanks already,
Bigflow

Comment: Aren't they in a Container so that you can take the container's children loop through them and check if the type is CheckBox and if it is then check if it is checked?

Comment: You must go for the CheckedListView it will return the position of the which is selected. Its not a good Practice to add 50+ checkbox in your Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround may be:

Suppose you have added `CheckBox` in `LinearLayout` and you can get the `LinearLayout` reference in Java and get the child Views like this:

```
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_container);
ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v;
        if(cb.isChecked())
        values.add(cb.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I used this one.
Had to modify I little bit, because I got:
  <Relative layout
  <ScrollView
  <TableLayout
  <TableRow
    Then Checkbox

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but: I also got TableRow1, TableRow2 etc.
But only 1 Tablelayout (all rows are inside this TableLayout, how can I check within all TableRows within the TableLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Array from CheckBox and than add them per code to you layout

```
CheckBox[] achecker = new CheckBox[50];
achercker[0] = new CheckBox(context);
```

or with an ArrayList is better when you dont know how much CheckBoxes you will need

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> lchecker = new ArrayList<CheckBox>(); 
lchecker.add(new CheckBox(context));
```

Answer (score 0):

set a listener to your checkboxes.`checkbox1.setOnCheckChangedListener(this)` then override

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
if ( isChecked ){
            // to determine which checkbox use buttonView.getId();
        }
}
```

Comment: so what you are suggesting him is to add listener to say 50 `CheckBox`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one below, set ID by count:

`ArrayList<Boolean> booleanList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();`

```
    for(int counter=0; counter<50; counter++) {
        booleanList.add(false);
        CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        chkBox.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        chkBox.setId(counter);
        chkBox.setOnClickListener(chkBoxOnClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener chkBoxOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        int chkboxID = ((CheckBox)view).getId();
        chkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(chkboxID);
            if(chkBox.isChecked()) {
                booleanList.set(chkBox, true);
            }

        }
}
```